# How to provide version number in library Zip folder

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am devloping a library for web application . There is a option to download to library as a zip folder. What is best way to provide version number in that zip folder. Is it good to provide a readme.txt file with the version details. Can anyone help me about best practice to provide version details in that library

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is name the library something like `{libraryName}-{version}.js`.

You can automate the naming by creating a script/utility application which takes the path to the library file and the version number as arguments (or prompts for them). The task of the script is to create a zip named  `{libraryName}-{version}.zip` with `{libraryName}-{version}.js` as content (by reading the content of `{libraryName}.js` and writing it to the zip.